# Java - Textbox text not visible

Tags: java

First time posting as SO usually has what I need but can't find this anywhere.

Working on Stanford's CS106A independently and I'm adding a textbox to the display.

The text box does not **VISUALLY** show any update. It either remains blank or remains with the text if .setText("some text"); is used. But the kicker is the text box does everything else it's supposed to, it just doesn't look like it does.

Just to clarify some confusion, my problem is **BEFORE** I hit the graph button or use the enter key. I can type anything I want in a blank space but I can't see it. I can delete any preset text completely or partially and type new text, I can't see that anything has been deleted or entered.

Once activating the e.getActionCommand() system will print out exactly what was typed or deleted, that part works perfectly.

What happens:
- textbox accept input (but not show the new text and does not change any existing text)
- e.getActionCommand() works and returns the text entered
- e.getSource() works and returns the text entered

Eg:
type "testing" into the text box
textbox visually continues to show "Enter a name"
name.getText() returns "testing"

```
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NameSurfer extends ConsoleProgram implements NameSurferConstants {

private static final int BUTTON_FONT_SIZE = 24;
private static final String BUTTON_FONT = "Serif";

public void init() {

    setSearchBar();     

}

private void setSearchBar() {

/* This method sets up the bottom search bar and interactors */


JLabel nameText = new JLabel("Name: ");
nameText.setFont(new Font(BUTTON_FONT, Font.PLAIN, BUTTON_FONT_SIZE));
add(nameText,SOUTH);

name = new JTextField(10);
name.addActionListener(this);
name.setActionCommand("Graph");
name.setFont(new Font(BUTTON_FONT, Font.PLAIN, BUTTON_FONT_SIZE));
name.setText("Enter a name");
add(name,SOUTH);

graph = new JButton("Graph");
graph.setFont(new Font(BUTTON_FONT, Font.PLAIN, BUTTON_FONT_SIZE));
add(graph, SOUTH);

clear = new JButton("Clear");   
clear.setFont(new Font(BUTTON_FONT, Font.PLAIN, BUTTON_FONT_SIZE));
add(clear, SOUTH);

addActionListeners();

}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if( e.getSource() == clear){
        println("Testing clear");
    }else if(e.getActionCommand() == "Graph"){
        println(name.getText());
        name.setText("Enter a name");           
    }

}

private JButton clear;
private JButton graph;
private JTextField name;

}
```

Comment: I don't work with that library, but one problem you have is here: `else if(e.getActionCommand() == "Graph"){`. Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here. Now I don't think that this is causing your current problem, but it will certainly cause a *future* problem and so you'll want to fix it.

Comment: Good catch, yes that would have been an issue but isn't causing this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

```
else if(e.getActionCommand() == "Graph"){
        println(name.getText());
        name.setText("Enter a name");           
    }
```

This line `name.setText("Enter a name");` is setting your text to `"Enter a name"` whenever an ActionEvent is triggered because your `setActionCommand` is always equal to `Graph` (assuming you applied the fix-up from @hovercraft-full-of-eels).

The reason that `name.getText()` is correct is because it returns that value before you call `name.setText("` in the action listener, but then immediately changes it back to `"Enter a name"` with `name.setText("Enter a name");`.

So to fix this issue just comment out or remove the line and test your code again:

```
else if(e.getActionCommand() == "Graph"){
        println(name.getText());
        //name.setText("Enter a name");           
    }
```

Then you need to think a bit on how you really want to reset the text field, and when it should be reset.

Comment: The issue occurs whether or not I set the name after reading the command.  If the text box is left blank both before and after the command (i.e. setText() is not called at all) I still can't see the typing.  Imagine a text box where anything you type isn't visible. Where anything that is set in the text box using SetText(" Some text") is visible, and can be deleted and replace, but visulally it will always remain "Some text" even as your fingers are still hitting the kyboard or backspace.  This occurs before I ever trigger the e.getActionCOmmand()

Comment: @cVer interesting, because this is an applet have you tried forcing a repaint by using `name.repaint();` or by repainting the parent by directly using `repaint();`

Comment: I've tried using 'name.repaint();' however, I'm not clear on where to place it. adding it to where the button is created does nothing.   I've also tried just making a small test program just to run a text field and I can't type in that one either. I'm starting to wonder if it has more to do with my JRE or Eclipse. Downloading a textbox example from online however works (already compiled)

Comment: Is the behavior the same if you compile and then run the compiled applet?

Comment: @sorifriend  its seems compiling and then running an executable is beyond my skill set atm (tried for last 45 min), I'll leave this for now and see if the Java meetup group I'm joining can help me. THANKS!!

Comment: @sorifriend just learned how to compile and create a Jar file, everything works fine in the executable

I'm going to try using intellij instead of eclipse and see if I make any more progress on the un-compiled version

Thanks again for the help!